# Fill List <string> from List <textbox>

Tags: c#, winforms, list

i have list of string

```
 List<string> names = new List<string> { "Ahmed Row 1", "Mohamed Row 2" , "asdsa","asdasadas","asdsadsa"};
 List<string> Ages = new List<string> { "22 Row 1", "30 Row 2", "12321321","354435","987987"};
```

and list of text boxes

```
List<TextBox> NamesTexbox = new List<TextBox>();
  List<TextBox> AgesTextbox = new List<TextBox>();
```

i want to fill the list of string from the list of text box

Comment: Are the two lists actually supposed to be aligned? In other words does `names[0]` related to `Ages[0]`? If so, you'd be better off with a single list containing a type that has `Name` and `Age` properties.

Comment: Well thanks for sharing but what's your question? Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read up on [System.Linq.Enumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable(v=vs.100).aspx) extension methods

```
names = NamesTextbox.Select(t => t.Text).ToList();
```

Or

```
names.AddRange(NamesTextbox.Select(t => t.Text);
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution I can think of is as follows:

```
names = NamesTextBox.Select(t => t.Text).ToList();
Ages = AgesTextBox.Select(t => t.Text).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using LINQ you can use foreach loops.

```
foreach(TextBox txtBox in NamesTexbox) {
     names.Add(txtBox.Text);
}
```